# Unable to use keyboard and mouse while using anydesk remote access if the display screen (lcd) is not plugged in on remote device

Tags: remote-desktop, anydesk

I am Unable to use keyboard and mouse while using anydesk remote access if the display screen (lcd) is not plugged in on remote device.i have multiple machines connected on lan but only one lcd so i have installed anydesk in all machines but i am unable to use keyboard and mouse if lcd is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to circumvent this is using a monitor emulator which can be obtained for a few dollars